# PHP Array'd POST Variable Name

Tags: php, arrays, forms, multidimensional-array, wordpress-theming

Using the following code I am attempting to:

1. Test to see if one of the dynamically assigned field names has been submitted;
2. Use the "Actionable Code" to process the submitted information.

My problem lies in I am incapable of retrieving the appropriate dynamic variable name. `$this->get_field_name('email_to')` will output a name variable such as `widget-mywidget[3][email_to]`; but to access this value via PHP I need it in the form of `$_POST['widget-mywidget'][3]['email_to']`.

How can I go about solving this dilemma?

**OUTPUTTED HTML:**

```
<form id="widget-mywidget-3-osiris_contact" method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="widget-mywidget[3][user_name]">
<input type="text" name="widget-mywidget[3][user_email]">
<textarea name="widget-mywidget[3][user_message]"></textarea>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="widget-mywidget[3][email_to]" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="widget-mywidget[3][email_subject]" value="">
<button type="submit" name="widget-mywidget[3][email_send]">Send</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**PROCESSING PHP:**

```
if(in_array($this->get_field_name('email_to'), $_POST)){ // <--- Where I need help.
    // Actionable Code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `$this->get_field_name` does:

```
  function get_field_name($field_name) {
     return 'widget-' . $this->id_base . '[' . $this->number . '][' . $field_name . ']';
  }
```

I suggest that you print_r($_POST) and compare it  visually for better debugging...
(Or use a debugger...)

Comment: The data is returned, that's not a problem; the problem is I don't know how to test for or access the dynamically named variable.

Comment: Haaaa... you're a genius! Took me a while to realize what you were saying, but perfect. I used the following: isset($_POST['widget-' . $this->id_base][$this->number].

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

```
$thing  = "widget-mywidget[3][email_to]";
$exp    = explode("[", $thing);
$get_it = $_POST['".$exp[0]."[".$exp[1]."[".$exp[2]."'];
```

Try, if it works.

Comment: This is not the way to handle variables in general... and you have an API to handle it...

Comment: What you have won't work exactly, but I see what you're getting at. I'll play around with it.